# SOAP - parsing variable from groovy to soap request

Tags: variables, for-loop, soap, groovy

I´m new in SOAP and need help :)I have a SOAP request which I would like to run five times and I need pass variable from for loop in groovy to request.

Example:

*for (i=1;i<5;i++){*

**SOAP request with passed i variable**

*}*

Another question: Is there any way, how to combine variables? I have a Properties with some data and I need combine this data with passed i variable 
Example:

${adress#City + **i variable**}

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming my_prop is the value you pass to your soap request

```
for (index=1;index<5;index++)  
{
    // set the index value in the property
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(my_prop, index.toString())
    // run your SOAP request
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("my_soap_test_step")
}
```

for your second problem you can do

```
new_prop = context.expand( '${#TestCase#old_prop}' ) + index.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks. That work. I have one more question: How to merge variables in XML request? 

I need merge this `<gser:Name>${adress#Name}</gser:Name>` with passed number. The result should be `<gser:Name>${adress#Name1}</gser:Name>`

Is this possible this?  `<gser:City>$(${adress#City}+${#TestCase#my_prop})</gser:City>`

Comment: well, I'm not very familiar with XML, use the new_prop example in my answer to create intermediate variables and try with it.

Comment: Problem solved :) This is OK: `<gser:City>${adress#City${#TestCase#my_prop}}</gser:City>`